# How do you say "much" and "a lot" in French? As in "I have studied a lot" or "I do not have much"?

Tags: grammaire, anglais, adjectifs, adverbes

How do you say "much" and "a lot" in French? As in "I have studied a lot" or "I do not have much"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"much" and "a lot" could be translated into "**trop**", "**beaucoup**", or "**autant**".

- I have studied **a lot**.
- J'ai **beaucoup** étudié.
- I do not have **much** time.
- Je n'ai pas **trop** de temps.
- Why don't **many** people know the philology ?
- Pourquoi **autant** de monde ne connait pas la philologie ?

Comment: Thanks! That cleared up a lot. I'm assuming you're not native so I'm going to also help you with your english just as you helped me :D "Why much people do not know the philology" is grammatically wrong you should say "Why don't many people know about philology", in English we don't generally put "The" before branches of knowledge.

Comment: Notice that all these words are not exact synonyms: "trop" means "too much" or "too many", "beaucoup" is "a lot", "much" or "many", "autant" can mean "as much", "that many"...

Comment: Merci pour ces petites précisions omises :)

Comment: chaplinmyflabbydog, you are right :) thank you

Answer (score 1):

A lot and much can have various functions and their interpretation in French may vary accordingly.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/much

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/a-lot

E.g.

> We still owe quite a lot. Nous devons encore beaucoup d’argent.
>
> This happens a lot. Cela arrive souvent.